# maven as project management and comprehension tool

Tags: maven

i have just started learning maven and came across the definition that maven is a project management and comprehension tool. I am not able to understand what makes maven a project management and comprehension tool

Comment: This article might help: http://www.technowlogeek.com/programming/maven/maven-build-and-project-management-comprehension-tool/

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the very [first page of Maven](https://maven.apache.org/)

> Apache Maven is a software project management and comprehension tool.
>   Based on the concept of a project object model (POM), Maven can manage a project's build, reporting and documentation from a central piece of information.

The "management" part is spelt out above.

The "comprehension" part is more vague, but detailed in "[Maven’s Objectives](https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html)"

> Maven’s primary goal is to **allow a developer to *comprehend* the complete state of a development effort in the shortest period of time**.
>   In order to attain this goal there are several areas of concern that Maven attempts to deal with:
>
> - Making the build process easy
> - Providing a uniform build system
> - Providing quality project information
> - Providing guidelines for best practices development
> - Allowing transparent migration to new features